# How to send array as search query parameter in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, search, get, e-commerce

I am building ecommerce platform and implementing advanced search functionality.
Here user can select multiple company and multiple group name for product search so that he can find certain multiple products at same time.
[image]

I am implementing select dropdown for each of group and filter is selected as such:

```
  $scope.getSelectedItems = function(item){
                 return item.selected;
     };
```

Data is selected as such

```
  <input type="checkbox" style="width:20px;height:20px;" ng-model="cmp.selected">{{cmp.compname}}
```

[image]

Selected Filter  Company is shown as such

```
<li ng-repeat="x in vm.cmpList |filter: getSelectedItems" " style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;">
                            {{x.compname}}
                        </li>
```

How can i send many values in filter to Get api so that all selectedItems are parameters ??

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to do use HttpPost and send your list as the request body

If you really want to use a get method you can add in the url as a query string

Comment: Cant understand can u explain?